# How to append items from scrapy spider to list?

Tags: python, macos, list, scrapy

I'm using a basic spider that gets particular information from links on a website. My code looks like this:

```
import sys
from scrapy import Request
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from properties import PropertiesItem, ItemLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess    

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic"
    allowed_domains = ["web"]
    start_urls = ['www.example.com']
    objectList = []
    def parse(self, response):
        # Get item URLs and yield Requests
        item_selector = response.xpath('//*[@class="example"]//@href')
        for url in item_selector.extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        L = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
        L.add_xpath('title', '//*[@class="example"]/text()')
        L.add_xpath('adress', '//*[@class="example"]/text()')
        return L.load_item()

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(BasicSpider)
process.start()
```

What I want now is to append every class instance "L" to a list called objectList. I've tried do to so by altering the code like:

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
        global objectList
        l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('title', '//*[@class="restaurantSummary-name"]/text()')
        l.add_xpath('adress', '//*[@class="restaurantSummary-address"]/text()')
        item = l.load_item()
        objectList.append([item.title, item.adress])
        return objectList
```

But when I run this code I get a message saying:

```
l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
NameError: name 'PropertiesItem' is not defined
```

**Q:** How do I append every item that the scraper finds to the list objectList?

EDIT:

I want to store the results in a list, because I can then save the results like this:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.DataFrame(objectList)   
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('DataAll.xlsx')
table.to_excel(writer, 'sheet 1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Yep @Granitosaurus done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save results you should use scrapy's Feed Exporters feature as described in the documentation [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports)

> One of the most frequently required features when implementing scrapers is being able to store the scraped data properly and, quite often, that means generating an “export file” with the scraped data (commonly called “export feed”) to be consumed by other systems.
>
> Scrapy provides this functionality out of the box with the Feed Exports, which allows you to generate a feed with the scraped items, using multiple serialization formats and storage backends.

See the [csv section](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-csv) for your case.

Another, more custom, approach would be using scrapy's [Item Pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html). There's an example of simple json writer [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file) that could be easily modified to output csv or any other format.

For example this piece of code would output all items to an `test.csv` file in project directory:

```
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feed_exporter_test'
    # this is equivalent to what you would set in settings.py file
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'test.csv'
    }
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath("//a[@class='question-hyperlink']/text()").extract()
        for i, title in enumerate(titles):
            yield {'index': i, 'title': title}
```

This example generates 50 row long csv file.

Comment: I cant seem to figure it out myself! Could you show me?

Comment: Thanks @Granitosaurus, it does work! However, scrapy saves the data to .csv in quite an inconvenient way. Since other people will use my app, I need to save the results in different columns, so that they don't have to do the excel manipulations. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @titusAdam What format are you looking for? Since now you know how to export feeds with scrapy you can open up a new question regarding the formatting and ordered of your data. CSV does have columns and can be opened, manipulated by excel or any other spreadsheet program.