# How to write scraped data into a CSV file in Scrapy?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a website by extracting the sub-links and their titles, and then save the extracted titles and their associated links into a CSV file. I run the following code, the CSV file is created but it is empty. Any help?

My Spider.py file looks like this:

```
from scrapy import cmdline
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class HyperLinksSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "linksSpy"
    allowed_domains = ["some_website"]
    start_urls = ["some_website"]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)

def parse_obj(self, response):
    items = []
    for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(),    deny=self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
        item = ExtractlinksItem()
         for sel in response.xpath('//tr/td/a'):
              item['title'] = sel.xpath('/text()').extract()
              item['link'] = sel.xpath('/@href').extract()   
        items.append(item)
        return items
 cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl linksSpy".split())
```

My pipelines.py is:

```
 import csv

 class ExtractlinksPipeline(object):

 def __init__(self):
    self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('Links.csv', 'wb'))

 def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.csvwriter.writerow((item['title'][0]), item['link'][0])
    return item
```

My items.py is:

```
 import scrapy

class ExtractlinksItem(scrapy.Item):
# define the fields for your item here like:
     title = scrapy.Field()
     link = scrapy.Field()

pass
```

I have also changed my settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'extractLinks.pipelines.ExtractlinksPipeline': 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output all data scrapy has inbuilt feature called [Feed Exports](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html).
To put it shortly all you need is two settings in your `settings.py` file: `FEED_FORMAT` - format in which the feed should be saved, in your case csv and `FEED_URI` - location where the feed should be saved, e.g. `~/my_feed.csv`

My related answer covers it in greater detail with a use case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41473241/3737009

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this? I tried your example given here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41473241/3737009), but nothing was written in to the csv file. 
Do you mean I hust need to place these two settings in my setting.py without the need to change any thing in my code? I guess I should disable the pipelineitems approach, right?

Comment: @owise yeah try to disable your pipeline. As long your spider returns any items the feed exporter will write them into your feed.