# Exporting scraped data to one CSV

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rbind

I managed to do a scraper for gathering Election info in `R(rvest)`, but now I am struggling with how I can save the data not in separate *CSV files*, but in the one *CSV file*.

Here is my working code where I can scrap pages 11,12,13 separately.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

do.call(rbind, lapply(11:13, 
                  function(n) {
url <- paste0("http://www.cvk.gov.ua/pls/vnd2014/WP040?PT001F01=910&pf7331=", n)
mi <- read_html(url)%>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
mi[[8]]

file <- paste0("election2014_", n, ".csv")
if (!file.exists(file)) write.csv(mi[[8]], file) 
Sys.sleep(5)
}))
```

I tried to do this in the end, but it is not working as I expected

```
write.csv(rbind(mi[[8]],url), file="election2014.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure that your URL is working? I'm getting a `HTTP error 400`.

Comment: Hi! I think that there is a typo in your url. Since you are trying a `get` request, a `?` should be somewhere in your url.

Comment: I edited URL. It has to work now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write scraped data into a CSV file in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510383/how-to-write-scraped-data-into-a-csv-file-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)


scr<-function(n){
  url<-paste0("http://www.cvk.gov.ua/pls/vnd2014/WP040?PT001F01=910&pf7331=",n)

 df=read_html(url)%>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE)%>%
    .[[8]]%>%
    data.frame()
 colnames(df)<-df[1,] 
 df<-df[-1,]
 }

res<-11:13%>%
  map_df(.,scr)
write.csv2(res,"odin_tyr.csv")
```

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to get your code to work, but you could try creating an empty data frame before running you code, and then do this before writing a csv file with the complete data:

```
df   = rbind(df,mi[[8]])
```

you could also consider turning your csv files into one using the purrr package:

```
files = list.files("folder_name",pattern="*.csv",full.names = T)

df = files %>%
  map(read_csv) %>%
  reduce(rbind)
```